# Is there any way to get rid of extra 0's from the end of array when using Arrays.toString() and also the square brackets '[ ]' from both ends?

Tags: java, arrays

I have written a program to convert an Integer in decimal to binary format :

```
int b=17,i=0;
int s[]=new int[10];
while(b>0)
{
    s[i]=(b%2);
    b=b/2;
    i++;
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s));
```

This prints : [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

But I want '10001' as output, for that, using a while() loop,

```
int j;
for(j=i-1;j>=0;j--)
{
    System.out.print(s[j]);
}
```

This prints : '10001' as I wanted, but is there any other way to get this output without using a loop?

Or

Is there a way to remove extra 0's in  [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], after 1,0,0,1 ?

Comment: you can simply remove elements from array after 10001 and then print the array

Comment: You can always write a method that does what you want (the implementation will likely use some loop). This can then be called simply with something like this `myArrayPrint(s,i)`

Comment: You need to print the array _in reverse_ and discard all leading zeros. That's not the same thing as discarding trailing zeros.

Comment: Why don't you just use [Integer.toBinaryString](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString(int))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't have an array from the start and append results to a `String`. This will eliminate a conversion array to `String`.

```
int b=17;
String result = "";
while(b>0)
{
    result = (b%2) + result;
    b=b/2;
}

System.out.println(result);
```

`String`s are also arrays of chars, so internally you don't dodge any array.

As @DodgyCodeException pointed, the original OP code for int to binary was producing reversed binary string/array. The above code is fixed with that already.

Comment: My previous answer was with Arrays.toString(), I didn't seen the title. But now I edited and seems to work. It still doesn't answer the question part about int array to String unfortunally.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer by editing it, such that others can learn from it

Comment: The digits also need to be in reverse. It's a pity the number 17 is a palindrome in binary.

Comment: Thanks @DodgyCodeException, fixed also.

Answer (score 1):

> but is there any other way to get this output without using a loop?

No matter how you do this, there *will* be a loop in the code somewhere, just not necessarily in the code *you* wrote. So I will interpret "without using a loop" as "without having to write a loop yourself".

One method is to use `Stream`s:

```
String result = Arrays.stream(s).map(x -> Integer.toString(x)).collect(Collectors.joining());
System.out.println(result);
```

You probably want to reverse the string as well, in which case you can do:

```
String result = Arrays.stream(s).map(x -> Integer.toString(x))
                .collect(
                    StringBuilder::new, 
                    StringBuilder::append, 
                    StringBuilder::append)
                .reverse().toString();
```

Another way is to directly create the string you want while you are converting the number to binary:

```
int b=17;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while(b>0)
{
    sb.append(b%2);
    b=b/2;
}
System.out.println(sb.reverse());
```

> Is there a way to remove extra 0's in [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], after 1,0,0,1 ?

Since the array size is fixed, you'd have to create a new array:

```
int[] withoutTrailingZeros = Arrays.copyOfRange(s, 0, i);
```

Comment: An undocumented but highly probable requirement is that the digits need to be output in reverse. It's a pity the same input is a binary palindrome, so both right and wrong answers look the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below:

```
String string = Arrays.toString(s);
System.out.println(string .substring(1, string .length() - 1));
```

**Edit1:**

```
        int b = 17;
        StringJoiner stringJoiner = new StringJoiner(",");

        while (b > 0) {
            stringJoiner.add(String.valueOf((b % 2)));
            b = b / 2;
        }
        System.out.println(stringJoiner.toString());
```

Comment: this just removed the square brackets  ' 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 '

Answer (score 0):

Do you mind using ArrayList instead of Array

```
        int b=17,i=0;
//        int s[]=new int[10];
        List<Integer> s = new ArrayList<>();
        while(b>0)
        {
            s.add(b%2);
            b=b/2;
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println(s.toString());
```

Comment: This is basically the same kind of output as Arrays.toString which is not the output the OP wants. (Also, it needs to be reversed.)

Comment: @DodgyCodeException I am supposing, the expected output is the same array  truncated with rear 0s removed